# Change text in many files

Tags: command-line, regex, text-processing

I have a C++ project, where each file has at its beginning some lines of license. Now, that my license have changed, I need to update it in each file. I don't want to do it manually, since its lots of work. Is there any way to make it more automatic? I tried http://regexxer.sourceforge.net/ but its only useful when dealing with short texts (it didnt replace my license) ...

My license:

```
/****************************************************************************
**
** Copyright (c) 2014, mirx
** All rights reserved.
**
** You may use this file under the terms of the BSD license as follows:
**
** "Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
** modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
** met:
**
**   * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
**     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
**   * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
**     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
**     the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
**     distribution.
**   * Neither the name of XYZ and its Subsidiary(-ies) nor the names
**     of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
**     from this software without specific prior written permission.
**
**
** THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
** "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
** LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
** A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
** OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
** SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
** LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
** DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
** THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
** (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
** OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE."
**
**
****************************************************************************/
```

I simply would like to add some lines to this code (replace with new version) = but how?

Comment: **-1** Well, this question is no way relevant to Ubuntu.

Comment: @devGeek: I know I can write a program that will do it for me, but thats not the point :) I thought I can use some existing solutions

Comment: "I simply would like to add some lines to this code (replace with new version) = but how?" use an editor that can changes multiple files at once? I tend to do this in aptana.

Comment: @KasiyA The AU site says, this is a site for Ubuntu users and ubuntu developers. The StackExchange network provides sites like (stackoverflow.com) and few more programming/coding relevant sites.

Comment: @KasiyA: The ideal solution would replace the whole license text (which I posted here) with its new version in each *.cpp and *.h file I have in my project.

Comment: This sort of question is fairly common on [so] and elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17567144 http://stackoverflow.com/q/8454525 http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26284/70524

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using [**awk**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/awk.1posix.html).

Create a new script `changeLicense.awk` like this:

```
{
  if (match($1,"^/\*.")!=0) {
     i = 0; flag = "false";
     comment[i++] = $0;
     while(getline > 0) {
       if (match($0,"Copyright") != 0) flag = "true"; 
       comment[i++] = $0; 
       if (match($0,"\*/$")!=0) {
         if (flag == "false") {
           for (J=0; J<i; J++) print comment[J];
         }
         else {
          while ((getline line < newLicense) > 0)
               print line;
          close(newLicense); 
         }
         next;
       }
     }
  } 
  print;
}
```

This script looks for block of lines inside `/*` and `*/` and if commented lines block contains "Copyright" string then replace block with newLicense file content, otherwise preserve comment.

In order to change license in all file of your project:

```
 find /path/project -name "*.cpp" -exec bash -c 'awk -f /path/changeLicense.awk -v newLicense=/path/fileWithNewContent $1 > $1.new; mv $1.new $1' _ {} \;
```

This script runs `changeLicense.awk` on each `.cpp` file found in `/path/project`, put result in `.new` file and than replace original `.cpp`

Tested on lubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

If the licence text always appears in exactly the same location in every file, then you could simply use `sed` to append the new text after a given line number e.g.

```
sed '34a \
** YOUR ADDITIONAL LICENCE TERMS\
** ADDED HERE
' file1.c
```

You could combine that with `find` to apply it to every `.c` file for example

```
find -name '*.c' -exec sed -i '34a \
** YOUR ADDITIONAL LICENCE TERMS\
** ADDED HERE
' {} \;
```

Comment: the goal is replace new license with new one, not append.

Comment: @KasiyA OP isn't very clear: "I simply would like to add some lines to this code" suggests append is ok, then says "replace with new".